# python - exporting dictionary(array) to json

Tags: python, json, dump

I have an array of dictionaries like so:

```
myDict[0] = {'date':'today', 'status': 'ok'}
myDict[1] = {'date':'yesterday', 'status': 'bad'}
```

and I'm trying to export this array to a json file where each dictionary is its own entry. The problem is when I try to run:

```
dump(myDict, open("test.json", "w"))
```

It outputs a json file with a number prefix before each entry

```
{"0": {"date": "today", "status": "ok"}, "1": {"date": "yesterday", "status": "bad"} }
```

which apparently isn't legal json since my json parser (protovis) is giving me error messages

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: `ok` isn't valid JSON. It should be `"ok"`. Make sure that that was a typo, and not an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list instead of a dictionary; you probably used:

```
myDict = {}
myDict[0] = {...}
```

You should use:

```
myList = []
myList.append({...}
```

P.S.: It seems valid json to me anyways, but it is an object and not a list; maybe this is the reason why your parser is complaining

Comment: While I have no idea why you'd want to, it should be totally valid to index a dictionary (both in Python and JSON) by number.

Comment: Sure, but when serialized to json, it produces an object, not a list

Comment: Right, which might not be what he wants to do; but it's valid.

Comment: I never stated otherwise, but the OP wrote: "I have an **array** of dictionaries like so", which, in fact, isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a JSON serializer...

Also, an array of dictionaries would better serialize to something like this:

```
[
    {
        "date": "today",
        "status": "ok"
    },
    {
        "date": "yesterday",
        "status": "bad"
    }
]
```

That is, you should just use a JavaScript array.